# Meaning of "period around now" in a description of the present continuous tense

Tags: phrase-meaning, present-continuous

I am learning from a book called *English Grammar in use*

The book says that we use the present continuous tense when we talk about changes happening around now and I am confused with the meaning of the "period around now".

Please help and give me some examples.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

"Period around now" means "starting recently and finishing soon".  What "soon" and "recently" mean is a matter of context.

> I play tennis.

(I can play tennis and I play frequently. I might not be on the tennis court now. Tennis is my sport.)

> I am playing tennis.

(I am on the court right now. I started earlier and I expect to finish soon. For tennis "soon" means in a few hours or less)

---

Sometimes the present continuous can emphasise the idea that the activity is in progress, and taking some time, it may indicate repetition:

> I'm jumping on the trampoline

(repeatedly jumping, the activity started recently and is taking some time.)

> I jump off the box.

(Single action, started and finished as you were speaking, quite a rare situation)

> I jump to school everyday.

(Statement of fact, not an activity that is ongoing right now).

---

Sometimes the continuous can emphasise the short period of time

> I live in London.

(statement of fact, not expected to end soon(

> I'm living with my parents.

(a temporary situation, expected to finish soon. In this case "soon" means in a few months or less.)

Comment: thank u a lot.That is really helpful